# How to automatically fill in form fields in django

Tags: django, forms, modelform

I have a modelform with four fields: message, author, room and timestamp. timestamp is set to auto_now and so does not appear in the form. Author and Room are both Foreignkeys and I want them to be filled out in the form automatically, author being set to request.user and the room being passed to view by the url: /add_message/{{ room.id }}/' The only field I want filled in by the client is the message. Here's the view so far, but I am not sure how to achieve this:

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def add_message(request, room_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Room, pk=room_id)
    m = Message.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')
    form = MessageForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        cmodel = form.save()
        cmodel.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('chat.views.add_message', args=(p.id,)))

return render_to_response('chatroom.html', {'contact_form': form, 'room':p, 'latest_message_list': m}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: I would like message to be typed by the client in the form and posted along with user and room which are defined in the view. request.user and room.id respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't test but should work

**forms.py**

```
class MessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.room = kwargs.pop('room', None)
        self.author = kwargs.pop('author', None)
        super(MessageForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        obj = super(MessageForm, self).save(commit=False)
        obj.room = self.room
        obj.author = self.author
        if commit:
            obj.save()
        return obj

    class Meta:
        model = Message
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def add_message(request, room_id):
    room = get_object_or_404(Room, pk=room_id)
    form = MessageForm(room=room, author=request.user, data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('chat.views.add_message', args=(p.id,)))
```

Comment: It certainly looks as if that would do the job, however, I've just tested it and raised a NameError stating: name 'forms' is not defined, I then changed forms.ModelForm to just ModelForm and it then complained: ModelForm has no model class specified.Otherwise, once this is cleared up that looks like what I'm after.

Comment: Did you specify Meta class inside MessageForm?

Comment: from django.forms import ModelForm
from chat.models import Message

class MessageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Message

Comment: if you write `from django.forms import Modelform` then you must define class like this: `class MessageForm(ModelForm):`

Comment: Yes, I did specify it I've got a few pastes here, save continuing this in the comments section:  http://pastebin.com/NuRrvQqr this is the old form. Here's your one which I modified to get working: http://pastebin.com/QMv2tNjN after that I returned it to your one and added from django import forms

Comment: Does it matter. I just add 2 methods that could not break your code. Check out indents or typos. `ModelForm has no model class specified` means error in Meta class